# jQuery get sent data back

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

how to get data back when using jQuery.get method ?

```
function send_data(pgId)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < pgId.length; i++)
    {
        // $.get(url, data, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR))
        $.get('index.php?page=' + pgId[i], pgId[i], function(respTxt, status, xhr)
        {
            if(status === "success")
            {
                alert("Data received: " + respTxt + "\n");
                alert("Data sent: " + pgId[i]); //<-- ???
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The parameter what I'm sending is optional, server doesn't accept that parameter, the only thing I want is that to pass that parameter to callback function when succeed to work with. pg_array is array of DIV ids.

I need to get sent data to process when ajax succeeds or at least pass that argument to custom callback when it succeeds.

I'm also new on web development so, apologies. I was searching a lot but I can't understand any of samples it showed.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a closure that will keep the value of the ID:

```
function send_data(pgId) {

    var callbackWithId = function (pgId) {
        //This will keep the pgId for the returned function
        return function(respTxt, status, xhr) {
            if(status === "success") {
                alert("Data received: " + respTxt + "\n");
                alert("Data sent: " + pgId);
            }
        }
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < pgId.length; i++) {
        $.get('index.php?page=' + pgId[i], pgId[i], callbackWithId(pgId[i]));
    }
}
```